# Microphone not working for team but works for group

Tags: overwatch

When I play in a group, I am able to use my microphone with no problems. However, when I turn on the microphone in the team voice chat, I am constantly broadcasting static to the rest of the team. There isn't any background noise that I can hear. I can see my name in the top left with the speaker symbol even when I am not talking or I mute my microphone. 
Does anyone know why this might be or what I can do about it?

Answer (score 1):

Are you sure you've set your microphone to `'Push-to-talk'` in the game's settings while you're in team chat?

If yes, then the game might be using some other recording device. Check and disable others in your windows sound panel under `Recording Devices`.

Comment: I have push-to-talk turned off intentionally. The part that is weird is that it doesn't have any problems when I am in a group voice channel, only on the team channel.

Comment: I had a similar problem when I forgot to disable the mic on my webcam. Do you have a webcam or other device with an integrated mic that might be broadcasting instead?

Comment: I tried it with push to talk and didn't have any issues. But it doesn't answer why I am getting static with open mic.

Comment: @JamesCW I unplugged everything just to make sure. I am using my laptop's built in microphone and it is still happening.

Comment: Have you tried disabling each and every single one of your Recording Devices?

Comment: @TheCaptan Built-in mics are notoriously bad.  Your computer's fans will usually be making lots of subtle vibrations that you can't hear but your mic will constantly be picking up.  I suggest getting an external mic - headphone/mic combos usually work best.

Answer (score 0):

If you're on PC press the "P" key by default to open the voice channel selection menu, then next to the blue "Team" tab press the icon that looks like a headset, this will put you in the team voice channel and allow you to speak to your team.